# Is it right extend an user controller in another user controller in MVC?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, software-design

I am in a situation where i am thinking in extend an user controller to eliminate code replication, but i am not sure if this can broke some MVC rule and if it is a good practice. To ilustrate, below is an code example.

```
class MyController extends CoreController {

    public function myMethod() {
        echo 'Hello world!';
    }
}

class OtherController extends MyController {

    public function otherMethod() {
        echo 'Hello life';
    }
}
```

Comment: I would say it is a good idea. I would do it like this.

Comment: Controllers should have almost no logic to begin with. Therefore it should negate any need for extending.

Comment: @tereško, What do you suggest to eliminate a method replication? The use of PHP traits is a good idea?

Comment: Your example is too simple and does not provide enough information for a conclusive answer. You can extend a CoreController to a specific one, and you should if it eliminates code replication. However, it might be happening because of some other bad design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use [PHP traits](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.traits.php), this way i can have a horizontal inheritance, eliminating the code replication and i think i am following the MVC principles.

```
trait Shared {

    public function sharedMethod() {
        echo 'Hello, i am sharedMethod()!';
    }
}

class MyController extends CoreController {

    use Shared;

    public function myMethod() {
        echo 'Hello, i am myMethod()!';
    }
}

class OtherController extends CoreController {

    use Shared;

    public function otherMethod() {
        echo 'Hello, i am otherMethod()!';
    }
}

$MyController = new MyController();
$MyController->sharedMethod(); // Hello, i am sharedMethod()!

$OtherController = new OtherController();
$OtherController->sharedMethod(); // Hello, i am sharedMethod()!
```